# Slide Card Style HTML CSS JS

Tags: css, slide

I'm looking to do a slide-card style website with html/css/js.

I have seen some nice examples like:

http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html

http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

However, what these DON'T seem to do is slide a page out WHILE the page underneath is visible, as if they were a stack of index cards. Parallax scrolling does this, but it typically will wipe the existing area, rather then scroll/move it off screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fiddle using JQuery that does something like what you are looking for, you could implement it with that one scroll effect of the card sliders and have it animate in probably.

http://jsfiddle.net/d6rKn/

```
(function(window){ $.fn.stopAtTop= function () {
var $this = this,
    $window = $(window),
    thisPos = $this.offset().top,
    setPosition,
    under,
    over;

under = function(){
    if ($window.scrollTop() < thisPos) {
        $this.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: ""
        });
        setPosition = over;
    }
};

over = function(){
    if (!($window.scrollTop() < thisPos)){
        $this.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: 0
        });
        setPosition = under;
    }
};

setPosition = over;

$window.resize(function()
{
    bumperPos = pos.offset().top;
    thisHeight = $this.outerHeight();
    setPosition();
});

$window.scroll(function(){setPosition();});
setPosition();
};
})(window);

$('#one').stopAtTop();
$('#two').stopAtTop();
$('#three').stopAtTop();
$('#four').stopAtTop();
```

See the fiddle for HTML and CSS.

Not my fiddle just grabbed it with a quick google search.